# DoCmd.OpenForm crashing Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a user login form on my access database with a table of users and other user criteria. One is a checkbox that if "true" will open up a change password form when the following code is ran. But when this checkbox field returns true, access 2010 crashes. So far, Google has left me empty handed. Any ideas on what would be causing the crash? Is it something in the code or could it be an issue with the "change password" form? The form opens just fine when I manually open it by "double clicking" it.

```
'Check if password needs to be reset
    If Me.cboUser.Column(3) = True Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPasswordChange", , , "UserID = " & Me.cboUser
    End If
```

The entire code is this:

```
Private Sub txtPassword_AfterUpdate()

'Check that EE is selected
If IsNull(Me.cboUser) Then
MsgBox "You need to select a user!", vbCritical
Me.cboUser.SetFocus
Else
'Check for correct password
If Me.txtPassword = Me.cboUser.Column(2) Then
    'Check if password needs to be reset
    If Me.cboUser.Column(3) = True Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPasswordChange", , , "UserID = " & Me.cboUser
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Opening Screen"
    Me.Visible = False
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tblAuditTrail ([DateTime], UserName, Action) VALUES (Now(),'" & Me.cboUser.Column(1) & "','Login')")
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Else
    MsgBox "Password does not match, please re-enter!", vboOkOnly
    Me.txtPassword = Null
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For the most part, if Access is crashing, it is time to back up, decompile and compact & repair.

Comment: That did the trick. It turned out some Functions were needing to be converted to use 64-bit systems.